# How can I modify a cert-manager resource via the python kubernetes client?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm using Python to automate creation of certain resources, and need to create a cert-manager Certificate. How do I access this via the python kubernetes client?

Normally I get the correct client using the format `client.<Group><Version>Api`, but I'm not sure  how to do that w/ 3rd-party resources such as the `Certificate` in `cert-manager.io/v1alpha2`.

Comment: Hi Ben, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, we ultimately went another route w/ our system (we switched to using Traefik, which has ACME support built in)

Comment: It is possible using [CustomObjectAPIs](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/d8f283e7483848647804eab345645106b6fb357d/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md) or by using the [dynamic-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/d8f283e7483848647804eab345645106b6fb357d/examples/dynamic-client)